# Wrong date come in pre-receive hook

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash, githooks

I trying to find the working branch name by using git command. Of course, I can able to get the proper branch name in my local (windows) machine. If I use the same command in pre-receive hook file means it prints only `master`. But in local I get the branch name where I have working.

command I using to get the branch is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

echo `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`

echo  `git branch | sed -n '/\* /s///p'`

echo `git status | head -1`

echo `git describe --all`
```

It is baffling! Any one suggest a correct way to get the working branch name in git hook file (`pre-receive` hook)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I think you are misinterpreting the role of a pre-receive hook and the `HEAD` of the repository in which the pre-receive hook runs.

#### Description

It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "working branch name".  However, it is true that *all* repositories have a `HEAD`, and `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` will print the name of the branch to which `HEAD` points (the "current branch"), even if that branch does not exist yet; or fail if it does not point to a branch name (i.e., is a detached HEAD).

That is:

```
$ mkdir tt
$ cd tt
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tt/.git
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
master
```

even though:

```
$ git branch
```

(note that there is no output)

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

(`git rev-parse HEAD` fails)

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

(the current branch is `master`, but there are no commits).

So `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` is probably the thing you're thinking about.  (Note that all of the above will continue to work, or fail, the same way in a new `--bare` repository, except for `git status`, which will say `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`.)

The main reason this makes little sense is that you also mention a pre-receive hook, and pre-receive hooks are mainly useful in centralized-server "bare" repositories that receive and accept push requests.  Remember that a bare repository is a repository that *has no work-tree*.  In a bare repository, the name of the branch to which `HEAD` points is almost entirely useless.  It has one actual function: it determines which branch a `git clone` of that repository will check out, provided the person running `git clone` does not specify a particular name to check out.<sup>1</sup>  In a normal, not-bare repository, `HEAD` would be the name of the branch that fills the work-tree of that not-bare repository; but since the bare repository does not *have* a work-tree, `HEAD` does no such thing.

But a pre-receive hook has, in general, no business consulting the *current* branch anyway.  A pre-receive hook is run with its standard input connected to a stream that will supply one or more lines of input.  Each line will have the form:

```
old-hash new-hash reference-name
```

e.g.,

```
3b136a71d875174d7539bf98080b85eaf415ba73 95ec6b1b3393eb6e26da40c565520a8db9796e9f refs/heads/foobranch
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0452b4b5786778d5d87f5c90a94fab8936502e20 refs/tags/v2.1.0
```

which in this case indicates that the sending Git would like the receiving Git to update branch `foobranch` from its current value of `3b136a71d875174d7539bf98080b85eaf415ba73` to the new value `95ec6b1b3393eb6e26da40c565520a8db9796e9f`, and create the tag `v2.1.0` pointing to object `0452b4b5786778d5d87f5c90a94fab8936502e20`.

***None of this depends on the current branch in any way.***  These update requests are provided by the Git that is doing the `git push`.  Since the receiving repository is (presumably, though you can check if you like) `--bare`, it has no work-tree and creating the tag, or replacing the value of `foobranch`, will therefore not affect that non-existent work-tree in any way.

---

<sup>1</sup>That is, when someone else makes a clone of this bare repository, that someone else *can* say `-b <branch-or-tag>`, but if that someone else *doesn't* say `-b <branch-or-tag>`, that someone else's Git will ask the bare-repository Git what branch its `HEAD` represents, and then set things up as if the someone else had specified *that* as the `-b` argument.

Comment: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` I used the same line on my hook. Actually, I commit my changes in my `test` branch and commit to it in local(windows), So `test` is my working branch! Am I right? Now push the changes into origin, in the hook the `echo \`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD\`` print `master` instead of `test`

Comment: Sure: `test` is *your* working branch. It's not the *other* Git's working branch. *There are two different Git repositories involved here.*

Comment: Is any other way to find the `test` branch in hook?

Comment: The current branch in *your* repository is irrelevant to someone who isn't *you*. The receiving Git can find which names you (or your sending Git) is requesting updates for, by reading the standard input, as I showed.